# find locations (from mutablearray) close to users location ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

)

i have an mutable array of restaurantObjects serialized form json data, if current object is named restaurantDetail i can acces corrdinates like this

```
float x = [[restaurantDetail.coordinates objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
float y = [[restaurantDetail.coordinates objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
```

so i would like to extract restaurants which are close to users location and store them to array

and if user changes location array should get updated too

i would really apprichiate help because i am completely lost here

i have tried this form Muthub Ram

```
- (void) checkIfInRegion{
Restaurant * currentRestaurant;
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
for(int i=0;i<[restaurantsArray count];i++){
    currentRestaurant = [restaurantsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    //NSLog(@"%@",currentRestaurant.coordinates);
    CLLocation * currentRestLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[currentRestaurant.coordinates objectAtIndex:0] floatValue], [[currentRestaurant.coordinates objectAtIndex:1] floatValue])
                                                             altitude:0
                                                   horizontalAccuracy:0
                                                     verticalAccuracy:0
                                                            timestamp:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"%@",currentRestLoc);
    if([locationManager.location distanceFromLocation:currentRestLoc] <100)
    {
        //if less than 100meters
        //then add object in this array
        [near_by_user addObject:[restaurantsArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",locationManager.location);
NSLog(@"restaurants near%@",near_by_user);
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}
```

i get all coordinates form location but i dont get any objects in near_by_user array ( it remains empty)

http://pastebin.com/fc8q69Le here is log, last set of coordinates is my location same as one of restaurants

Comment: Did you have a look at Apple's "Core Location Framework Reference", for example the CLLocation class?

Comment: which api you are using....because in most of api they take a radius parameter also. so if there is a parameter in your api then set its radius

Comment: i am using this api https://github.com/mrfoto/bonar it doesn have any radius :) its for restaurants for students in slovenia

Comment: You should not assume that locationManager.location will be available immediately after calling startUpdatingLocation.  Also, is near_by_user an NSMutableArray and did you call alloc+init on it?

Comment: thanks for alloc+init reminder solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   for(i=0;i<[array_res count];i++){
    if([clloc distanceFromLocation:[array_res objectatindex:i]<100])
    {
    //if less than 100meters
    //then add object in this array
    [near_by_user addobject:[array_res objectatindex:i];
    }
    }

please add this code.if you have any clarification update here
```

Comment: You left out the important part - the implementation of `distanceFromLocation:`.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#jumpTo_12
**it predefined function in cllocation**